# NVME can't see S.M.A.R.T. in gnome-disk-utility

Tags: 16.04, ssd, smart, nvme, gnome-disk-utility

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I bought an nvme ssd (Intel 600p) and am no longer able to view SMART data through **gnome-disk-utility**.

I was able to see SMART using my old SATA ssd through this dropdown menu:

[image]

With the NVME ssd, the menu option doesn't exist. I can still view SMART data for the NVME ssd using

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme
```

Why can't I also view it in gnome-disk-utility?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in the underlying *udisks* program used by gnome-disks.
There already exist a issue on the gitlab page https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/issues/50 and upstream on the *udisks* issue tracker https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/386

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have the latest firmware installed in the Intel 600P. Go to these web sites for the downloads...

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/memory-and-storage/000017245.html

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/94922/Intel-SSD-600p-Series

In the `Disks` utility, make sure that you select the SSD in the left pane, then go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`. That should get you where you want to go.

You might install `gsmartcontrol` and see if that sees the SSD SMART.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gsmartcontrol
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 to get more or less the same data

```
sudo nvme list
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
```